# Using jq to filter AWS resources based on their tags

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli, aws-resource-group

Using the command `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --profile (profile_name)` returns an array of JSON object with the Resource ARNs value and their tags (another array of JSON of objects with tag's key and value.

Here's a anonymized example:

```js
{
  "ResourceTagMappingList": [
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:123456789000:certificate/XXXXX-YYYY-8888-9999-CCCCCCCCCCCCC",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Environment",
          "Value": "BAR"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:123456789000:certificate/XXXXX-YYYY-8888-9999-CCCCCCCCCCCCC",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Environment",
          "Value": "FOO"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:123456789000:elastic-ip/eipalloc-112345440809463",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Component",
          "Value": "somethingCool"
        },
        {
          "Key": "DeployID",
          "Value": "di-01"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "eip-nat-somethingCool-di-01"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:123456789000:elastic-ip/eipalloc-19853410278439394i3",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Component",
          "Value": "somethingCool"
        },
        {
          "Key": "DeployID",
          "Value": "bla-internal-goku"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "eip-nat-somethingCool-bla-internal-goku"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "ResourceARN": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:123456789000:targetgroup/tf-20190624192221842800000004/oisajhiuweniçqej82u23948u3",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Component",
          "Value": "somethingCool"
        },
        {
          "Key": "DeployID",
          "Value": "env01-bla00"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Environment",
          "Value": "env01"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Estate",
          "Value": "something"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "target-group-lala-somethingCool-env01-bla00-vsquad"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I would like to know if I can use the [cli tool jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter the objects based on a specific tag Value? And if it is possible to list out all Value of a specific Tag Key?

Comment: You can achieve the same also without any external tool by using the `--query` option of the AWS CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter objects based on a specific tag value:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region REGIONCODE \
    | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(.Tags[0].Value == "VALUETYPE")'
```

List all values of a specific tag key:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-tag-values --key KEYNAME
```

Comment: Doesn't work as expected as is it only looking at the first tag and not all of them and when removing the number from Tags it apparently shows some duplicate values.

Answer (score 2):

You can query for all tag values for the specified key in the specified region for the AWS account, by calling the same API, but get-tag-values.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/resourcegroupstagging/latest/APIReference/API_GetTagValues.html

Answer (score 0):

`aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region "$AWS_REGION" --tag-filters Key=TAG_NAME | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(any(.Tags[] ; .Key == "TAG_NAME" and .Value == "TAG_VALUE"))'`

Note the `--tag-filters Key=TAG_NAME` in the `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi` command itself, so that AWS doesn't bother returning any resources without the desired tag.

If you want to do partial (substring) matching on `.Value`, use this:

`aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region "$AWS_REGION" --tag-filters Key=TAG_NAME | jq '.ResourceTagMappingList[] | select(any(.Tags[] ; .Key == "TAG_NAME" and (.Value | contains("SUBSTRING"))))'`

Note that `.Value == "TAG_VALUE"` has been replaced with `(.Value | contains("SUBSTRING"))` (and the brackets wrapping this are needed, because of operator precedence wrt `and`